# Rally - array does not contain all pushed elements

Tags: rally

I have an app that I am trying to use but it seems that while iterating through arrays and pushing into another array.i.e combining the arrays into one is not working for me. Example  - I see all 213 pushes to this array but when I check its contents they are less.

Here is the code that shows me incomplete array push list.

For 213 test cases test set only 67 are pushed and present in the array

```
that = this;
                that._testSetTestList = [];
                console.log('testsetdata',testsetdata);

                Ext.Array.each(testsetdata, function(record) {
                console.log('record.get(TestCases)',record.get('TestCases'));
                    Ext.Array.each(record.get('TestCases'), function(name, index) {
                        that._testSetTestList.push({
                            resID: name.FormattedID,
                            resName: name.Name,
                            resObject: name.ObjectID,
                            resSetID: record.get('FormattedID'),
                            resSet: record.get('Name'),
                            resSetObject: record.get('ObjectID'),
                            resSetProject: name.Project.ObjectID                        
                        });
                        console.log('_testSetTestList.push',{
                            resID: name.FormattedID

                        });
                    });
                });
```

Can anyone guide me to what I am doing wrong if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example of using promises from [this github repo](https://github.com/markwilliams970/Artifacts-With-Attachments), here is a code that builds a grid of test sets with their collection of test cases, where elements of array of test sets `setsWithCases` is pushed in to another array `testsets`, and the second array is used to populate the grid. The second array contains all elements of the first array. I am using [LowDash](http://lodash.com/docs) _.each, included with AppSDK2.

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentsCls: 'app',

    launch: function(){

        var aStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
            model: 'TestSet',
            fetch: ['ObjectID', 'FormattedID', 'Name', 'TestCases'],
            autoLoad: true,
            context:{
                projectScopeUp: false,
                projectScopeDown: false
            },
            listeners:{
                scope: this,
                load: this._onStoreLoaded
            }
        });
    },
    _onStoreLoaded: function(store, records){
        var setsWithCases = [];
        var testsets = [];
        var that = this;
        var promises = [];

        _.each(records, function(testset){
            promises.push(that._getTestCases(testset, that));
        });
        Deft.Promise.all(promises).then({
            success: function(results) {
                _.each(results, function(result) {
                    if (result.TestCases.length > 0) {
                        setsWithCases.push(result);
                    }
                });

                _.each(setsWithCases, function(testset){
                    testsets.push(testset);
                });
                that._makeGrid(testsets);
            }
        });

    },

    _getTestCases:function(testset, scope){
        var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
        var that = scope;

        var testcases = [];
        var result = {};

        var testsetRef = testset.get('_ref');
        var testsetObjectID = testset.get('ObjectID');
        var testsetFormattedID = testset.get('FormattedID');
        var testsetName = testset.get('Name');
        var testcaseCollection = testset.getCollection("TestCases", {fetch: ['Name', 'FormattedID']});
        var testcaseCount = testcaseCollection.getCount();

        testcaseCollection.load({
            callback: function(records, operation, success){
                _.each(records, function(testcase){
                    testcases.push(testcase);
                });
                result = {
                    "_ref": testsetRef,
                    "ObjectID": testsetObjectID,
                    "FormattedID": testsetFormattedID,
                    "Name": testsetName,
                    "TestCases": testcases 
                };
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }
        });

        return deferred;
    },

    _makeGrid:function(testsets){
        var that = this;

        var gridStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
            data: testsets,
            pageSize: 1000,
            remoteSort: false
        });

        var aGrid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            itemId: 'testsetGrid',
            store: gridStore,
            columnCfgs:[
                {
                   text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate') 
                },
                {
                    text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', flex: 1
                },
                {
                    text: 'TestCases', dataIndex: 'TestCases', flex:1,
                    renderer: function(value) {
                        var html = [];
                        _.each(value, function(testcase){
                            html.push('<a href="' + Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl(testcase) + '">' + testcase.get('FormattedID') + '</a>' + ' ' + testcase.get('Name'));
                        });
                        return html.join(', ');
                    }
                }

            ]
        });
        that.add(aGrid);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code instead:

```
this._testSetTestList = Ext.Array.flatten(Ext.Array.map(testsetdata, function(record) {
    return Ext.Array.map(record.get('TestCases'), function(name, index) {
        return {
            resID: name.FormattedID,
            resName: name.Name,
            resObject: name.ObjectID,
            resSetID: record.get('FormattedID'),
            resSet: record.get('Name'),
            resSetObject: record.get('ObjectID'),
            resSetProject: name.Project.ObjectID 
        };
    });
}))
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the output is still the same. I did a step by step debugging and saw that during iteration and pushing the 'that._testSetTestList' received all 213 test case objects but as soon as it goes out of the outer 'Ext.Array.each' (iteration is over) the array suddenly has fewer elements, is it possible that scope or filter of some sort is applied implicitly as soon as the pushing stops?

Answer (score 1):

The issue in my case was not the code but the scope..I was trying to get the test case results for test cases that were not directly reachable in the project tree. We have the test cases residing in several projects but then we use them in test sets under different projects. If the test cases that are part of the queried test sets are directly reachable for the project for which we view this page, then test case results were accounted for BUT if the test cases were in projects that were siblings to the one that view the app from then the query could not find them and take their test case results. The solution was to consolidate all test cases under the correct project so that the app can access them from any required project.